# Topology without tears

Tags: general-topology

I have started reading the book [*Topology Without Tears*](http://uob-community.ballarat.edu.au/~smorris/topology.htm) by Sidney A. Morris. I have read the first chapter and so far it reads well. However, the name of the book is a bit deceiving and makes me think it is not a book to rigorously learn topology. Has anyone read (or) used the book? If so, could you let me know if it is a nice book to start with? If not, could you let me know what book I should use to learn topology? (I would prefer a free book available online. It is quite expensive to buy a good book in India. However, if it is "the" book and I must have if I want to learn topology then I shall consider buying it.)

Thanks,
Adhvaitha

Comment: I've never seen this book before, but he begins the first chapter by stressing the importance of proofs, so I'm not very worried about the rigor. We shouldn't discourage creative titling!

Comment: Are the 'tears' referenced in the title the type that drip from your eyes, or the type that rip things into pieces?

Comment: My students loved the book, it's pretty good. And it is rigorous.

Comment: Started to exercise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's a good book to learn topology. The author takes some space to talk about intuition, but all definitions, theorems, proofs are rigorous.

(Side note: Looking at your user profile, you might be falling in the calculus trap. Please read [this article](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/articles.php?page=calculustrap).)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is good book that I recommend for its self-completeness. You will not have to go to other sources to understand the book. This is very important quality for the book you choose as your first in a topic.
Also watch [Mr. Morris's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/sidlmorris/videos) where he lecturing. Specifically I like his lecture series about mathematical proofs.